# BibTeX: add "+" to preprint's creation year

Tags: bibtex

I'm using BibTeX wit the `.bst` file "alphaabbr" that writes a key with the names abbreviated and the publication (or creation, for preprints) year.
For instance: [ABC17] for three authors A, B and C and a paper written in 2017. It is similar to [XZ17] a preprint with creation year 2017.

I would like to find some other `.bst` extension that provides [XY17+] for a preprint. I already saw it used by colleagues, so that it should exist?

However, I could not find the proper `.bst` file on the web.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can ask your colleagues how they did it. How do you indicate preprints in your `.bib` file? Can you show us a short compilable example document (with a few relevant bib entries), so that we can be sure to talk about the same thing and can get started more quickly?

Comment: Can you also please tell us where you get `alphaabbr.bst` from? A short search suggests it is not on CTAN.